# How to get response after the UPI payment is done in flutter/dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Can someone please help me how to get hold of the response once the UPI transaction is completed. I have used this help in Stack Overflow but it is not working: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48097332/how-can-we-get-response-from-an-app-which-was-launched-by-another-app".

In my case when I incorporate this it is saying MissingPluginException(No Implementation Method Found).

```
class _DisplayCartItemState extends State<DisplayCartItem> {
  static const platform = const MethodChannel('upi/tez');
  Uri uri;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    uri = Uri.parse('upi://pay?pa=*****@okhdfcbank&pn=Test App&tn=Payment Done through Foodie App&cu=INR&am=1');
  }

_startPaymentTransaction(BuildContext context) async {
        if (await canLaunch(uri.toString())) {
          try {
            final String result = await platform.invokeMethod('launchUpi', <String, dynamic>{"url": uri.toString()});
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
              content: Text(result),
            ));
            print(result);
          }catch(e){
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
              content: Text(e.toString()),
            ));
          }
        } else {
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
            content: Text("Could not launch the UPI App"),
          ));
        }
      }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can somebody please help?

Answer (score 2):

```
void _launchURL() async {
    String _url='upi://pay?pa=dinesh@dlanzer&pn=Dinesh&am=1&tn=Test Payment&cu=INR';
    var result = await launch(_url);
     debugPrint(result.toString());
     if (result ==true) {
       print("Done");
     } else if (result ==false){
       print("Fail");
     }
  }
```

Try this code

I use [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) plugin for open UPI apps.

Deeplink url `'upi://pay?pa=dinesh@dlanzer&pn=Dinesh&am=1&tn=Test Payment&cu=INR'`,

`upi` show list of UPI apps you have in your mobile.

`pay` is redirect to payment page.

`pa` you mention upi address here (please make business upi account and mention here).

`am` amount enter here.

`tn` just pass massage.

`cu` mention which currency you want to make payment

Comment: Please provide an explanation. See [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I use [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) plugin for open UPI apps. Deeplink url 'upi://pay?pa=dinesh@dlanzer&pn=Dinesh&am=1&tn=Test Payment&cu=INR', 
`upi` show list of UPI apps you have in your mobile. 
`pay` is redirect to payment page. 
`pa` you mention upi address here (please make business upi account and mention here). 
`am` amount enter here. 
`tn` just pass massage. 
`cu` mention which currency you want to make payment

Comment: Ok then you can edit your answer instead of commenting.

Comment: ok bro I will edit my answer

Comment: hey @dineshbalan, what would response have, can we have a callback url or something

Comment: No, This method is only called UPI application, and you did not get any response, If you want a response please use a payment gateway like Razorpay, Cashfree & PayTM. I prefer  Cashfree & PayTM because for UPI 0% fess.